# How can I thank this community math stack exchange for help me with my doubts in my thesis?

Tags: discussion

I am studying a paper with this community helps, and I would love to thank you!

How can I do this officially? I mean, I am not going to publish any paper, but I would like to thank this community and let my university knows about this. Besides, I would like that this can be known here too.

Comment: You can name the question number or the exact stackexchange link, which was helpful for you. I have seen this very often now in a thesis, also as a footnote for a certain result you are using.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Good hint. Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand why someone downvoted me.

Comment: It was not me, but I can understand that the question is not about mathematics as explained in the help center.

Comment: It was good of you to post this as an actual question... but yes, simply thank the specific users in the specific questions/answers!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know was not you because of your first comment, no worries. lol And thanks again.

Comment: @FShrike ok, good hint again. I did not know about this. I've seen many questions here that are not associated with math helps exactly, then because of this, I thought there was not any problem.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372898/1114922 I posted there, they deleted and they told me that there is not the right place.

Comment: Another way to thank math.se is to **pay it forward**.  Help others who ask questions;  work on the review queues; ask additional interesting questions.

Comment: In any case, @Silvinha, Please know that many of us appreciate your efforts to graciously say "thanks".  Not everything makes sense on stack exchange sites, like downvotes when a user is trying to thank users on this site, but your kind intentions are appreciated by most of us.

Comment: Given your link above, give your thanks locally, @Silvinha, on the site you are thankful.  Upvotes on helpful posts are always appreciated, and a way to say thanks, and for any answer you believe helped you the most, you can say "thank you" by clicking on the "grey checkmark" to the left of all answers; when you click it, it turns green, and that is what is meant by "accepting an answer".  But stay local, within any site that you've been helped.

Comment: @GEdgar how to pay?